# What is the meaning of bool operator () (int num)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, operator-keyword

Is **()** used in the **bool operator()(int num)** of the below code a another operator or it means something else ? Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class IsOdd{
    public:
        bool operator()(int num){
            return ((num%2)==1);
        }
};
int main(){

    vector <int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    vector <int>::iterator pend;
    vector<int>:: iterator q;

    pend = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsOdd());
    for(q=v.begin(); q!=pend;++q)
        cout<<*q<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) - especially the function call operator

Answer (score 1):

That means overloading the operator () to work with the IsOdd class.

Here is a sample of code of the overloaded operator in action:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

class IsOdd {
public:
    bool operator()(int num) {
        return ((num % 2) == 1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    IsOdd isOdd; // Defining object isOdd of the class IsOdd

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isOdd(v[i])) std::cout << v[i] << " is odd." << std::endl;
        else std::cout << v[i] << " is not odd." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've also removed the iterators and shown with a much simpler way to iterate through elements in a std::vector.

Also, you should not use the following in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

...as it's considered as bad practice.

### Output:

```
1 is odd.
2 is not odd.
3 is odd.
4 is not odd.
5 is odd.
6 is not odd.
7 is odd.
8 is not odd.
9 is odd.
10 is not odd.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a function, and the `()` is part of the name - `operator()` is a special spelling for "function that is used to make an object behave like a function".
(It's a bit strange to call it "operator", but the C++ committee prefers reusing keywords to introducing new ones.)

If you have an object of the `IsOdd` type, such as

```
IsOdd is_odd;
```

then what looks like a regular function call,

```
is_odd(3)
```

is transformed behind the scenes into

```
is_odd.operator() (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsOdd` is a functor class. It has an overload of the function call operator, so that given an instance `x` you can call it via `x(42)` to determine if `42` is odd.

In the code it is used to pass a callable to the algorithm. Nowadays you would rather use a lambda:

```
    auto isOdd = [](int x) { return ((num % 2) == 1);};
    pend = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), isOdd);
```

or perhaps, if the functor is only needed for the algorithm but not elsewhere, define the lambda in-line:

```
    pend = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x){ return ((num % 2) == 1);});
```

---

> Is () used in the bool operator()(int num) of the below code a another operator or it means something else ?

Here:

```
pend = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsOdd());
```

the `()` in `IsOdd()` is a call to the constructor to create an instance of the class `IsOdd`. The `operator()` of that instance is then called by the algorithm. If you like you could also call it yourself:

```
auto x = IsOdd();    // call constructor
std::cout << x(42);  // call operator()
```

Answer (score -5):

It means it's a function named operator(), returns a boolean, and takes in an integer named num.

Edit:
Its an overloaded function operator so you can have it take no arguments or the argument int num.

Comment: That's not correct - this is a overloaded function operator

Comment: _"you can have it take no arguments or the argument int num"_  That's also not correct - it expects an `int` parameter.